# Central isogenies differ by an element of the maximal torus

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G, G'$ be connected, reductive groups over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$.  A *central isogeny* is a surjective morphism of algebraic groups $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ with finite kernel such that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $U_{\alpha}$ onto its image, for all $\alpha \in \Phi(G,T)$.

If $\phi$ is an isogeny, then $\phi T = T'$ is a maximal torus of $G'$, and $\phi$ induces a homomorphism of character groups $f(\phi): X(T') \rightarrow X(T)$ which is an *isogeny of root datum*, which is to say that $f(\phi)$ is injective with finite cokernel, it is a bijection on the roots, and its dual is a bijection on the coroots.

I'm confused about the argument given in (ii) of the following proposition (T.A. Springer, Corvallis Proceedings):

[image]

I think the point of the proof is to use the fact that given scalars $0 \neq c_{\alpha} \in k : \alpha \in \Delta$, there exists a $t \in T$ such that $\alpha(t) = c_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$.  In this way, $t$ can be chosen so that $\phi \circ \textrm{Int}(t)$ and $\phi'$ agree on all the simple root subgroups $U_{\alpha}$.

Now, it is written "$U_{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \Delta$ together with $T$ generate $G$," but this is wrong: one needs $U_{\pm \alpha} : \alpha \in \Delta$.  But in that case, I don't see how $t$ can be chosen so that $\phi \circ \textrm{Int}(t)$ and $\phi'$ agree on both $U_{\alpha}$ and $U_{-\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in \Delta$.

Comment: That definition of central isogeny is ad hoc and archaic: prove it's equivalent to $\ker\phi$ being finite and contained in the scheme-theoretic center $Z_G$ ($Z_G \subset T$ since a maximal torus in a connected reductive group is its scheme-theoretic centralizer).  To finish your fix of the error in the proof of (ii): if $B$ is the Borel subgroup containing $T$ corresponding to $\Delta$, and $\phi$ and $\phi'$ agree on $U_a$ for all $a\in\Delta$, then $\phi|_B=\phi'|_B$, so the $k$-morphism $\phi'\cdot\phi^{-1}:G\to G'$ with affine target factors through the *proper* $G/B$ and so equals 1.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a stupid question, but when $\phi'$ and $\phi$ are *isomorphisms*, I can take $\phi^{-1}$ and use the completeness/properness of $G/B$. When $\phi$ is merely an isogeny, what is the meaning of $\phi^{-1}$?

Comment: By $\phi^{-1}$ I don't mean an inverse map; I mean the map of varieties $g \mapsto \phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(g^{-1})$.